# how my browser know which kind of json object should it create for a specific site?

Tags: json, http-headers, jsonresponse

i wonder how my browser know which field it should create for a json and add it to the request header?
i mean when you go to  different sites and for example login or send buy request etc. how my brower know which field it should create for json?
i go to a specific site and send a order request but when i analyze the request header every time i send the order there is a field in json that change,but i send the exact request every time but it change,
i want to create a artificial request but i don't know how to generate that field!!
how i can generate it like my browser?

Comment: Is that field named CSRF token or something equivalent ?

Comment: nope,the change happen in a filed in json object,there is a field called category id and it change every time,even tho i buy exact same product with exact amount and exact price every time!,i think its something for prevent bots to send post req,but how my browser generate it?! and how i cant generate it too?

Comment: Your browser doesn't generate the field contents. The server does

Comment: but the change happen in json in sender header not in respone header